# Camera in 3D view somehow not working

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I just finished an animation project, and suddenly my camera is looking really weird.

The camera has 2 child of modifiers, to two empties (circle and sphere)
I haven't animated the camera at all, only animated the empties

I believe I have pressed a shortcut (I'm a noob and I dont know all of them).
I've searched around the internet but unfortunately cant find a solution, I dont even know what this is called.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks to me like you made an object the active camera. Select the real camera and press `Ctrl` `NumPad 0`

Comment: Like @David said, you made an object the active camera. Notice in the top left corner of the second screenshot in the 3d view it says, "Object as Camera"

Answer (score -1):

hit **STRG-ALT-NUMPAD0 to set the selected object as the active camera.** Currently you have an object as the active camera. The small triangle above the camera tells you whether it is active or not (**filled triangle = active, triangle with just contours = currently not active**)